# Bad superblock repeats every Xubuntu 18.04.1 reboot

Tags: boot, 18.04, xfce, hp, fsck

UPDATE: The problem occurs after booting Windows 10

In my Xubuntu 18.04.1, when I try to boot, it gets stuck on a black screen, so I press the power button to force shutdown. Next time I try to boot I get bad superblock key on /dev/sda5 (my case) error.

My current solution is to boot Xubuntu from a LiveUSB flash drive and check disk partitions with this command

```
fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda...
```

The problem is, I need to do this on every boot. Is there any other solution to my problem and why is it happening?

Edit: More info about my device (it dual boots with Windows 10): HP [15-ay055nx](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-ay000-notebook-pc-series/10862300/model/15831487/document/c05411164) 15" Notebook [1HH00EA#A2N](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-ay000-notebook-pc-series/10862300/model/15831487?sku=1HH00EA) with Intel® HD Graphics 400, 01/05/2017, 81EB: [Manual A](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06189781)  or  [Manual B](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06189775)

Comment: You need to avoid force shutdown.

Comment: Graphics card? Have you installed any drivers?

Comment: And the graphics card is...?

Comment: @K7AAY Provided it

Comment: @K7AAY My release is 18.04.1 LTS bionic, And yes Xubuntu, I didn't change the environment